# Android: How to position image correctly

Tags: android, image, position

Hi all  I want to know how to position an image within a liniearlayout using java not xml. I am creating the image like this:

```
TextView Streets = new TextView(this);          
Streets.setText("Text");                        
Streets.setPadding(140, 25, 0, 25);
Streets.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (R.drawable.bus, 10, 10, 10);
Streets.setTag(i);
```

As you can see I am setting the padding of the image but I want to know how to set the image to be toStartOf a TextView.

Comment: Do you mean setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()?

Comment: write what do you want to do in xml format so that we can get what are you ahead to do

Comment: basically what I want is to set the image at the begging of a text

in XML should look like this:

  android:layout_toStartOf="@id/TextViewID"

Answer (score 2):

To set an image to the left (start) of a `TextView` you don't need an `ImageView`.

You can use

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

In your case you only need to set the drawable on the left.

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (R.drawable.bus, 0, 0, 0);
```

---

*After your code update:*

You are giving the function `10` as an argument for top, right and bottom. So the function is trying to find a drawable which has an id equal to 10, which probably doesn't exist.

Use `0` instead.

Comment: this seems not to be working the image is not displayed at all.

Comment: Why are you giving 10 as an argument? The textview is trying to find an image which has an id = 10... Use `null` instead.

Comment: If I use null I get: The method setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, null, null)